# C# MongoDb FindAndUpdate (many)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

From the name `FindOneAndUpdate()` I understand this is an **atomic operation**.

**What if I want to find 10 items (Limit(10)) and Update them all alike?**
For example set a state field to "in progress"?

Is that atomically achievable with MongoDb? Is there some built-in functionality in the C# driver maybe? I don't want to implement 2PC myself if it is avoidable :-)
I have other consumers asking for documents as well, I therefore want to avoid double processing although it is not critical to my business case.

The motivation *NOT* to use `FindOneAndUpdate()` 10 times is purely networking (less chatter, and better performance) related. I do not have a requirement for transaction-like behavior.

The database nor the business case is under my control but I was told to expect many documents going in and out rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, operations are only considered atomic on a per-document basis. That is, if you update multiple fields in a document with a single update statement, you will get all of the updates or none of them should they be queried while the update is happening. That means an update that affects more than one document will not be an atomic operation across all documents, but will be atomic within the document.

Since it sounds like you are concerned with being more efficient with sending commands to the server, not so much as to whether or not the operation is atomic server side, you can use [`BulkWriteAsync()`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollectionBase_1_BulkWriteAsync.htm) which takes a `IEnumerable<WriteModel<TDocument>>` of updates to perform on the server.

This allows you to build a list updates and execute them in one operation to the server. Care must be taken during this process to properly handle failed writes. Take a look at the MongoDB Docs on this over [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/).